# The amperage of batteries in parallel configuration

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

I made a circuit using phet colorado's simulation online, and I have two batteries in a parallel configuration with one light bulb outside the batteries parallel configuration. Note: both batteries are 9.0 volts and the light bulb has 10.0 resistance. When I check the amperage of the wire that comes from one battery, it has 0.45 amps.  When I check the wire that has both of the batteries' 'electricity' (I don't know the word for that) it has 0.90 amps. Why does the one battery wire have 0.45 amps while the wire that is connected to both batteries have 0.90 amps?

Comment: Have you heard about Kirchhoff's Current Law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law?

Comment: How would you find the total amperage , the amperage of the wires connected to the light bulb?

Comment: It's the sum of the two battery currents or you can use Ohm's law on the voltage across the light bulb and the light bulb's resistance. Both ways you will get the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batteries are put in parallel so as to "split the load" as shown in the examples below.

[image]

You will note that in both circuits the current through the resistor is $0.90\,\rm A$.

In the top circuit all of that current is provided by the top battery whereas in the bottom circuit each battery provides $0.45\,\rm A$.

Also note that at node (junction) $X$ the sum of the currents entering the node are equal to the sum of the currents leaving the node: $0.90 + 0.00 = 0.90$ for the top circuit and $0.45 + 0.45 = 0.90$ for the bottom circuit.

This is Kirchhoff's current law in action.

Comment: Thank you. I have experimented that as well. Why is it that they split the load? What's going on in the particle level when that happens?

Comment: In this case half the mobile electrons go one way and half the other way as would happen to water in a pipe which then divides into two identical pipes.